# Где хранится история звонков iphone

Tags: ios

Пытаюсь считать звонки из базы iphone. Делаю согласно [инструкции](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/). По идее должно быть по крайней мере 4 базы -

```
var/db/launchd.db,
var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBook.sqlitedb,
var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBookImages.sqlitedb,
var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db.
```

У меня находится только первая. Искала *call_history.db* где только можно, не нашла. Где может храниться история звонков? Запускаю приложение на ios6.

Comment: Статья старая, как не скажу что. Если Вы почитаете комментарии к статье за этот год, то автор там говорит, что доступ к базе данных с историей звонков был заблокирован. Так что лепите куличики в своей песочнице! :)

Answer (score 1):

В iOS6 и позже эту функциональность убрали. (все это есть в комментариях к статье)